# how to query mongodb with equivalent of SQL like

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have this code:

```
 let collection = database.collection('Product')

let doc = await collection.find({"Product_Name": /req.query.Product_Name/}).toArray()

console.log(doc)
```

I have a product (ex) called `Test Product (22in)`

so I want someone to be able to search `Test Product`, and it should come up, however, my code ins't doing that. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe remove forward slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are trying to provide a regex pattern, need to use [`$regex`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) query operator.

```
let doc = await collection.find({
  "Product_Name": {
    "$regex": "Test Product",
    "$options": "i"
  }
}).toArray()
```

Note: the option `i` is for Case insensitivity. You can read more about the operator adn hwo regex matching behaves in the docs.

Side note: Regex matching over a large number of documents is expensive and you could consider bulding an index (text) for the feild where search is required.

See an example [playground link here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sEmow4wtmQr)